# How in i display label with form field in collections of forms in symfony2

Tags: php, forms, symfony, doctrine-orm

I have this table

`Tasks -- id , name`

`usertasks -- id, task_id , note`

```
Class user {
private $ usertasks
}
```

My form for usertask is like this

```
public function buildForm(FormBuilder $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
            ->add('note')


        ;
    }
```

The form is showing fine.

Is there any way that before the `note` text field i can have the label of task name

something like

```
$builder
 ->add('usertask.getName(id)) as Label not editable               
 ->add('note')
        ;
```

Answer (score 0):

you can set the label in any field by using configuration options

```
    $builder->add('idtype', 'text', 
        array(
            'label' => 'your label',
            'empty_value' => '',
            'preferred_choices' => array('0', '1', '2'),
            'required' => 'true'
        ));
```

You also can use a variable to set the value:

```
    $builder->add('idtype', 'text', 
        array(
            'label' => $value,
            'empty_value' => '',
            'preferred_choices' => array('0', '1', '2'),
            'required' => 'true'
        ));
```

Comment: but i need to get that value from form itself.

Comment: Use the object to set the value: 'label' => $userTask->getId()